# INDEX/MATCH, or another function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have on `Sheet1` 18 columns:

N a list where an `Order Number` can be selected
O a `Line number` (as the orders have multiple line numbers associated with them)
P, Q and R, I want to pull over the data associated with the `Order Number` and `Line number` entered. The data it is pulling from will be on another workbook but I've copied it into another sheet (`Sheet3`) to try to get it to work.

My formula looks like this:

```
=Index(Sheet3!$A:$E,MATCH([@[Order Number]],Sheet1!$N:$E,0),3)
```

I want it to look at `Sheet3` and say "I see this `Order Number` and this `Line number`, here is what I have for that combination in Columns C, D and E of `Sheet3`, place these in columns P, Q and R on `Sheet1` respectively".

I did find one answer in here that is extremely close to what I am looking for but it doesn't work for me either:

```
=Index(Sheet3!$A:$E,MATCH(N5 & "|" & O5,Sheet3!$A:$E & "|" & Sheet3!A:E,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "near miss" looks as though it used a helper column. Insert a ColumnC into Sheet3 and in C1 there enter:

```
=A1&"|"&B1
```

Copy that down to suit. In your other sheet in ColumnP (Row1 ? - or adjust the `N` and `O` row references to suit) enter:

```
=VLOOKUP($N1&"|"&$O1,Sheet3!$C:$F,2,0)
```

and copy across to R1. Adjust Q1 from `,2,` to `,3,` and R1 from `,2,` to `,4,` then copy down to suit.